# How can I add a whole row as a column name in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data set as follows:

```
sureste_1 sureste_2 ... sureste_136

1 CO NO NOX O3 ...
```

So what I want to do is to drag the whole row into the column names, so it says:

`sureste_1_CO sureste_2_NO sureste_3_NOX ...` and so on.

Makes sense?

Comment: will there be just 1 row? if not please share the logic for multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For append values to columns names by first row use:

```
print (df)
  sureste_1 sureste_2 sureste_3 sureste_136
1        CO        NO       NOX          O3
```

---

```
#row with label 1
df.columns = df.columns + '_' + df.loc[1]
#first row
#df.columns = df.columns + '_' + df.iloc[0]
print (df)
  sureste_1_CO sureste_2_NO sureste_3_NOX sureste_136_O3
1           CO           NO           NOX             O3
```

Another idea with list comprehension and `f-string`s:

```
df.columns = [f'{k}_{v}' for k, v in df.loc[1].items()]
print (df)
  sureste_1_CO sureste_2_NO sureste_3_NOX sureste_136_O3
1           CO           NO           NOX             O3
```